# Populating Activity based on SQLite query and Join in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, android-sqlite

I should start off by noting I am extremely new to Android Development so sorry if my question seems dumb.  I am trying to query my SQLite Database in the application to dynamically create the content on the activity.  Here is the query in my Database Helper file

```
    public Cursor getWhereToEatActivity (int LocationId)
{
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT Location.locationId as _id,Location.title,Location.desc, location.address, location.hours, location.website, location.phone FROM " +
            "TripWhereToEat JOIN Trip ON TripWhereToEat.tripId = Trip.tripId JOIN Location ON " +
            "Location.locationId = TripWhereToEat.locationId where TripWhereToEat.tripId = ?",
            new String[] {Integer.toString(LocationId)});

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor;
}
```

Here is where the item is selected:

```
 @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                LocationListitem locationItem = (LocationListitem)lvItems.getItemAtPosition(position);

                int locationId = locationItem.getLocationId();

                // Pass the ID into the next activity
                Map<String, String> parms = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parms.put("locationId", Integer.toString(locationId));
                if (listType.equals("whattosee")) {
                    // switchActivity(WhatToSeeActivity.class, parms);
                }
                if (listType.equals("wheretostay")) {
                    // switchActivity(WhereToStayActivity.class, parms);
                }
                if (listType.equals("wheretoeat")) {
                    switchActivity(WhereToEatActivity.class, parms);
                }
              }
            });
```

And here is the activity is switches to:

```
public class WhereToEatActivity extends FragmentActivityBase {

private int LocationId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_where_to_eat);

    AndroidApplication app = (AndroidApplication)getApplication();

    DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = app.getDatabase(); // new DatabaseHelper(this);

    LocationId = Integer.valueOf(this.getParam("LocationId"));

    Cursor tripRecord = myDbHelper.getWhereToEatActivity(LocationId);

    tripRecord.moveToFirst();

    if (!tripRecord.isAfterLast()) {
        String name = tripRecord.getString(tripRecord.getColumnIndex("title"));
        String title = tripRecord.getString(tripRecord.getColumnIndex("desc"));
        String image = tripRecord.getString(tripRecord.getColumnIndex("image"));
        String address = tripRecord.getString(tripRecord.getColumnIndex("address"));

        ImageView mainImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("com.integrativelogic.roadtrip:drawable/"+image, null, null); 
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),resId);
        if (bitmap != null)
            mainImageView.setImageBitmap (bitmap);    

        TextView nameView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        nameView.setText(name);

        TextView titleView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

        titleView.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
        titleView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        TextView addressView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
        addressView.setText(address);
    }

    tripRecord.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

And this is the error I get from Logcat:

```
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.integrativelogic.roadtrip/com.integrativelogic.roadtrip.WhereToEatActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1821)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1842)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:362)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:506)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at com.integrativelogic.roadtrip.WhereToEatActivity.onCreate(WhereToEatActivity.java:27)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
01-12 11:23:52.186: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
```

Comment: What is your actual value of LocationId  in  
  Cursor tripRecord = myDbHelper.getWhereToEatActivity(LocationId);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you're new I'll explain a bit on the debugging process when you have a sudden crash of your app like this:

1st part is read the last few lines of the LogCat output:

> > Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer

so we know that is a problem trying to make an empty string be an integer. You can only create an integer from a String that contains numbers.

a few lines below that one on the Log you'll see

> > at com.integrativelogic.roadtrip.WhereToEatActivity.onCreate(WhereToEatActivity.java:27)

so then we know that it happens on the line 27 of your WhereToEatActivity, I'm not gonna count the lines of what you posted here but I'm assuming it's this line

```
LocationId = Integer.valueOf(this.getParam("LocationId"));
```

so I guess it's safe to assume that the reason you're having this error is because there is no parameter "LocationId" or the parameter is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You error is right here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
```

I suspect you have an empty location here:

```
LocationId = Integer.valueOf(this.getParam("LocationId"));
```

if that line is referenced here:

```
at com.integrativelogic.roadtrip.WhereToEatActivity.onCreate(WhereToEatActivity.java:27)
```